# Transaction Exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do simple hibernate saving data to my table but I have Transaction Exception in the console, here is my code :

```
logging.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "Logging")
public class Logging implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String user;
    private String action;
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "action")
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

and that's my insertion method:

```
public class BaseDAO {
    public SessionFactory factory;

    public Session session;

    public BaseDAO() {
        factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(
                "hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public void save(Object obj) throws Throwable {
        session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

my loginServlet where i'm saving my data :

```
Logging loggingdto = new Logging ();
try {
    loggingdto.setId(1);
    loggingdto.setUser(loggedInUserDTO.getUserName());
    loggingdto.setAction("USER LOGGED IN");
    loggingdto.setDate(new Date());
    base.save(loggingdto);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my table in DB

```
create table Logging(
id int not null,
user_name varchar(50) not null,
action varchar(50) not null,
Date date 
primary key (id)
);
```

another issue that appears in the console the hibernate print that the data is inserted to the table but with wrong order like that

```
Hibernate: insert into Logging (action, DATE, USER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and it should be like that

```
Hibernate: insert into Logging (id, user_name, action, date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

when i check the table i found it empty ??

Comment: Add stacktrace of transaction exception please.

Comment: Also, add your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file as well!

Comment: @ N00b Pr0grammer i'm sure that my hibernate.cfg.xml is correct

Comment: @ Alexander Podkutin it's already coded

Comment: Where is the exception stacktrace? Post it please!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the column name specified in the query to create the table and in the Logging.java file. 
That's why your console shows

```
_Hibernate: insert into Logging (action, DATE, USER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)_
```

instead of
    _Hibernate: insert into Logging (id, user_name, action, date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)_